# Can GetFileAttributesW handle url-encoded spaces (%20) in file paths?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, filepath

Function call:

```
OS_WRAPI::GetFileAttributesW(file_name_str); // file_name_str value is L"C:\\Test%20Tool\\test.exe"
```

returns  `INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES`.

Function call:

```
OS_WRAPI::GetFileAttributesW(file_name_str); // file_name_str value is L"C:\\TestTool\\test.exe"
```

returns valid attributes.

Both paths exist.

How can I get the file attributes in the case of url-encoded spaces (%20) in the file path?

Comment: "%" is not a reserved character in Microsoft's filesystems. With exception of ASCII control characters 0-31, the path separators (`\/`), the file-stream delimiter (`:`), the 5 wildcard characters (`*?"<>`) and vertical bar (`|`) (not actually reserved for anything), Microsoft's filesystems allow all other 16-bit UCS-2 characters. They even allow reserved surrogate codes that aren't paired in valid UTF-16 surrogate pairs.

Comment: If you have a url-encoded path you need to unurl-encode it yourself before you pass it to the Windows filesystem functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can GetFileAttributesW handle spaces in filepaths?

Yes.

Note that `L"C:\\Test%20Tool\\test.exe"` does not contain a space. Probably you should be passing `L"C:\\Test Tool\\test.exe"`.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileattributesa) says:

> If the function fails, the return value is `INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES`. To get extended error information, call `GetLastError`.

So you should, in case `INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES` is returned, call `GetLastError`. I'd expect that to return `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND`.

If the question is actually

> Can GetFileAttributesW handle `L"%20"` in filepaths?

The answer is still yes. If that path really exists, and `GetFileAttributesW` is returning `INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES`, then there must be some other problem, but the presence of `L"%20"` in a file name presents no problems for the Windows API. Again start by calling `GetLastError`.

Perhaps what's really at issue here, is that you think that Windows uses `L"%20"` to encode a string in the file system. It does not. On the file system, `L"%20"` and `L" "` are two distinct names.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I changed the question according to your comment. Actually what I was interested in was: why GetFileAttributesW can not handle the encoded space "%20"?

Comment: You expectation about the last error was correct: ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND.
I also can get the file attributes when I replace "%20" by " ". So my suggestion is that your last point is not correct: GetFileAttributesW can not handle the "%20". It needs a " ".

Comment: If youre callign `GetFileAttributesW("Foo%20.txt", ...`, windows will be looking for a file called  literally `Foo%20.txt`. The `%` character is an ordinary characters for the Windows file system which doesn't know anything about character encoding such as used with html.

Comment: Create a file named `L"C:\\Test%20Tool\\test.exe"` and you will find that `GetFileAttributesW` will happily give you its attributes.

Comment: Ok, let me paraphrase. 
The ```GetFileAttributesW``` needs a space if there is a space in the path. If you try to use ```GetFileAttributesW``` with encoded space, it will not find your path without encoded space. 
So no, ```GetFileAttributesW``` can't handle "%20" as a space, it is used like as a literal.

Comment: That's not at all what I meant. There's just no HTML style encoding going on here at all. You can have a file named `L"%20"` if you want. I thoughts that's what you were meaning at one point.